# Set border radius for a container with different width

Tags: flutter

I created a Container with different border widths. I am trying to set borderRadius to this container but I am getting this error:

`A borderRadius can only be given for uniform borders`

I tried to use a Stack which wrapped two containers. I was partially successful, but not quite what I wanted.

Here is my code:

```
   Container(
                margin: PaddingConstant.paddingAll,
                height: 60,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadiusConstant.borderRadiusCircularMedium,
                        border: const Border(
                          top: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
                          left: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
                          bottom: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
                          right: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadiusConstant.borderRadiusCircularMedium,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom:
                                BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.black),
                            right:
                                BorderSide(width: 5, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
```

**And this is the output:**

[image]

**But Expected**:

[image]

Comment: use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Border/Border.all.html and btw you don't need that `ClipRRect` - use `BoxDecorarion` shadows instead

Comment: thank you for replying but this link doesn't show me what i want to do. And I don't want to add shadow. I want to set the width of the Top and Left border to 2 and the width of the Bottom and right border to 5.

Comment: Probably, I did not describe my problem well. The "Border.all()" method sets all borders to the same color and width. I don't want all the edges to be the same size. I want Top and Left border, Bottom and Right border to be a different width. If you look at the photo I added to my question, you will understand more clearly what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions Mr @pskink. I'm new to Flutter. this didn't work because I used Border.all() method without BoxShaaddow. My fault. Now, it works perfectly. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use Stack and ClipRRect. This design can be easily created with BoxDecoration's boxShadow, border and borderRadius property:

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.cyan.shade100,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black,width: 2),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                offset: Offset(3, 3),
              )
            ],
          ),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: const ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            title: Text("Title"),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.check_circle_sharp,color: Colors.blue,),
          )
        )
```

[image]

the border is equal for all sides but Offsetting the shadows in x-y axis does the magic.